# MOXy JSON Serializer Cannot Serialize Java Proxy Class with an interface extends other super interfaces

Tags: json, eclipselink, moxy

Use Case:

We designed a modulated framework based on JOOQ, which is a DSL for SQL. Each Module will have an API sub-module and IMPL sub-module. At API level, for each ReadOnly access, we only expose a specific "view" interface to avoid bring confusions, which contains getters only.

To bridge the model and the ReadOnly View, we use java Proxy.

So there would be some high level interface, which concrete level can extend from. And then we met the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: The java interface example.json.demo2.IAddress can not be mapped by JAXB as    it has multiple mappable parent interfaces. Multiple inheritence is not supported
- with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50089] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20140809-296a69f):      org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The java interface example.json.demo2.IAddress can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces. Multiple inheritence is not supported]
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1108)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init>(JAXBContext.java:188)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
at example.json.demo2.Demo.main(Demo.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-50089] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20140809-296a69f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The java interface example.json.demo2.IAddress can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces. Multiple inheritence is not supported
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException.invalidInterface(JAXBException.java:1116)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.javamodel.reflection.JavaClassImpl.getSuperclass(JavaClassImpl.java:360)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postProcessXmlAccessorType(AnnotationsProcessor.java:1626)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.buildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:844)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.postBuildTypeInfo(AnnotationsProcessor.java:773)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.AnnotationsProcessor.processClassesAndProperties(AnnotationsProcessor.java:298)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.<init>(Generator.java:156)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1104)
... 11 more
```

ReadOnly View Interface:

```
@XmlRootElement
public interface IAddress extends A, B {

@XmlPath("/address/@streetAddress")
String getStreet();

void setStreet(String street);

@XmlPath("/address/city/@cityName")
String getCity();

void setCity(String city);

@XmlPath("/address/state/@stateCode")
String getState();

void setState(String state);
@XmlPath("/address/country/@countryCode")
String getCountry();

void setCountry(String country);

@XmlPath("/address/@postalCode")
String getPostalCode();

void setPostalCode(String postalCode);
}
```

Two super interface:
     `public interface A {}`
     `public interface B {}`

Bean Class:

```
@XmlType(propOrder = { "country", "state", "city", "street", "postalCode" })
public class Address implements IAddress {

@XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:Thoroughfare/ns:ThoroughfareName/text()")
private String street;
@XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:LocalityName/text()")
private String city;
@XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:AdministrativeAreaName/text()")
private String state;
@XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:CountryNameCode/text()")
private String country;
@XmlPath("Placemark/ns:AddressDetails/ns:Country/ns:AdministrativeArea/ns:Locality/ns:PostalCode/ns:PostalCodeNumber/text()")
private String postalCode;

@Override
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

@Override
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

@Override
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

@Override
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

@Override
public String getState() {
    return state;
}

@Override
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

@Override
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

@Override
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Override
public String getPostalCode() {
    return postalCode;
}

@Override
public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
}
}
```

Runner Class:

```
public class Demo {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final FileReader xmlURL = new FileReader("src/main/java/example/json/demo2/response.xml");
    final FileReader jsonURL = new FileReader("src/main/java/example/json/demo2/response.json");

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[]{Address.class, IAddress.class}, new HashMap());
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    // XML
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(xmlURL);
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
    xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to kml tag
    xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to Response tag
    JAXBElement<Address> addressFromXML = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Address.class);
    marshaller.marshal(addressFromXML, System.out);

    // JSON
    unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
    unmarshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
    StreamSource json = new StreamSource(jsonURL);

    final JAXBElement<Address> addressFromJSON = unmarshaller.unmarshal(json, Address.class);
    marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.media-type", "application/json");
    marshaller.setProperty("eclipselink.json.include-root", false);
    final IAddress value = (IAddress) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Demo.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{IAddress.class}, new InvocationHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            final Address address = addressFromJSON.getValue();
            return method.invoke(address, args);
        }
    });
    marshaller.marshal(value, System.out);
}
}
```

And BTW, if I commented the as:

```
public interface IAddress {//extends A, B {
```

Then I can get:

```
{
  "address" : {
  "postalCode" : "94043",
  "streetAddress" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy",
  "city" : {
     "cityName" : "Mountain View"
  },
  "country" : {
     "countryCode" : "US"
  },
  "state" : {
     "stateCode" : "CA"
  }
}
}
```

I tried with MOXy 2.6.0-M3, and it still has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what the answer should be, but their appears to be some issues that are preventing it from working:

### Option #1 - Change the Super Type of `IAddress`

You could use MOXy's external mapping document to specify that the super type of `IAddress` is `java.lang.Object`, or just one of `A` or `B`, instead of `A` and `B`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings 
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="example.json.demo2">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="IAddress" super-type="java.lang.Object"/>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

This overriding works for classes, but MOXy seems to have an issue when this is used on interfaces, see the following issue:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/455272

### Option #2 - Remove `A` & `B` from the Inheritance Hierarchy

Alternatively you could use `xml-transient` to remove `A` and `B` from the inheritance hierarchy (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/ignoring-inheritance-with-xmltransient.html).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="example.json.demo2">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="A" xml-transient="true"/>
        <java-type name="B" xml-transient="true"/>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

This overriding works for classes, but MOXy seems to have an issue when this is used on interfaces, see the following issue:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/455273

### Applying the External Metadata

The mapping file is applied when  creating the `JAXBContext` as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, "example/binding.xml");
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("example", Customer.class.getClassLoader() , properties);
```